# hue-shift given rgba value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to use a canvas to draw an image with a colored filter over it. As css has the hue-shift filter, I'm using that to apply on the canvas. The catch is that I have a palette and I want to shift the color via the color the user presses on the palette. I've already gotten the RGBA value from clicking on the palette - I'm just not sure how to use this to create a color filter for the image itself.

```
function changeColor2(e) {
    x2 = e.offsetX;
    y2 = e.offsetY;
    var imageData2 = firstContext2.getImageData(x2, y2, 1, 1).data;
    rgbaColor2 = 'rgba(' + imageData2[0] + ',' + imageData2[1] + ',' + imageData2[2] + ',1)';
    colorLabel2.style.backgroundColor = rgbaColor2;
    console.log(rgbaColor2);
    context.filter= 'grayscale(100%)' + 'sepia(100%)';
    //context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + imageData[0] + ',' + imageData[1] + ',' + imageData[2] + ',1)';
}
```

Where would I go from here to get the color shift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `"hue"` blending mode will do for you:

- You draw the image where you want to apply the color shift.
- You set the context's `globalCompositeOperation` to `"hue"`.
- You fill a rectangle of the target color over the whole image.

```js
const inp = document.querySelector("input");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image();
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/300/300";
img.decode().then(() => {

  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  inp.oninput = e => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "hue";
    ctx.fillStyle = inp.value;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  };
  inp.oninput();

});
```

```html
<input type=color value=#cca633><br>
<canvas></canvas>
```